# Queued for installation over six hours

Tags: software-center

I am running Ubuntu Mate 18.04.  It is just installed and looks to be running fine.  I have been trying to install the additional software "software Centers" shown on the Software Boutique.  When I key the install button it shows "Queued for installation".  I let it run over six hours but the install never completed.  I have run the software updater and fixes (broken packages & outdated files) and everything seems OK.

Is a queue that lasts that long normal?  Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Please refer https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/installing-software-programs-in-queue-software-boutique/16653 - you have to start the install...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install through Boutique, it is queued, it allows you to queue several packages. But you have to tell it to start install after you selected all packages you want.

On the right top is a button "Bulk Queue", press it, it will show you all that is queued. Then press "Apply changes"

Comment: ok, I just realized I described exactly what guiverc put into a comment